# Uncaught TypeError ONLY in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typeerror

I#ve a very strange problem calling a simple function in JavaScript.

Just for example, even a simple:

```
<a href='#' onclick="javascript:alert(123);">click</a>
```

or:

```
<a href='#' onclick="alert(123);">click</a>
```

gives me an **Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function**.
But ONLY in Chrome and ONLY on my Notebook. On my Workstation (same system, exactly same Chrome Version) and in every single other browser this line works as expected.

Im Working with JS since a few years, but this error drives me nuts since days.

The Website comes with scriptaculous and some handwritten JS, but nothing really special.
scriptaculous works well, JS-Console shows no errors except the one @Chrome on my Notebook.

Anyone of you ever had this before?
I#ve really no idea whats going on.

---

Comment: The `javascript:` label is useless in the onclick, do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to assign it via javascript and not like an inline attribute. Sometimes you get odd behaviour setting it as an attribute.

You could use jQuery:

```
jQuery('.myClickableLink').click(function(){ alert(123) })
```

I think that's a simpler way.

Comment: Yes, maybe thats the only solution. but then i would have to reconcept the whole technologie of the website cause everythings is based on scriptaculous. but maybe this is the point to switch to jQ...

Comment: Damn. with jQ i got **Porperty 'alert' of object is not a funtion**

Answer (score 0):

I am betting you have a pop up blocker installed on that machine that hijacks window.alert. Disable the plugins and see if it works correctly. [Normally a pop up blocker does this]

Comment: Nope, no pop up blocker installed in Chrome. And the alert(); was just for example. Doesnt matter if I call another function onclick. the Error is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
window.alert('msg)';
```

it will work...